# Two list have 1 element both and show the repetition

Tags: prolog

I have an exercise today that there was two lists, `list1` and `list2`,there will be the result that should calculate how many zeros(0) are from `list1` and `list2`. This should be the N that shows the repetition of zero. Conclusion we have:
`List1` is `[1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0]` and `list2` is `[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]`. What I have done is

```
[1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0], [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],Result).

%and_list([Head| Tail], [Head| Tail2]) :-
 %   p(Head),
 %   and_list(Tail, Tail2).

and_list([Head| Tail], List) :-
    \+ p(Head),
    and_list(Tail, List).
p(0).


?- and_list([1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0], List).
List = [0, 0, 0 , 0] ;

?- and_list([1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],List).
List = [0,0,0,0] ;


%how many times  0

result(N,[],0).
result(H,[H|T],X) :-
    result(H,T,XT),
    X is NT+1.
result(N,[H|T],N) :-
    N\=H,   % N\==H 
    result(N,T,X).
```

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: my question is if the code is right?I mean, the way i did it is right?

Comment: i tryed to do this "I have an exercise today that there was two lists, list1 and list2,there will be the result that should calculate how many zeros(0) are from list1 and list2. This should be the N that shows the repetition of zero. Conclusion we have: List1 is [1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0] and list2 is [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]. What I have done is" into the code i give.

Comment: Yes, I can read your post. You do not have to repeat it in a comment. It's not a question. And asking "Is this code right?" is too broad.  In your example, you did not  say what result you expect for `N`. You should run/debug your code and ask a more specific question about a specific issue you encounter if you have trouble.

Comment: No,i just wanted to know if the way i did it was good :) thanks

Comment: For N i expect how many times will show the zero .Example 5 lets say

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "was good". "Good" in what way? This site is for problems, not really for code reviews for improvement (efficiency, readability, or whatever). What does 5 mean as a solution? It's unclear.

Comment: i mean if what the exercise was telling me to do ,if my code was in the way what the exercise was asked about

Comment: It's unclear what you want it to do. You said you want to get a result `N`. You have a predicate that takes 3 arguments: an integer, a list, and another integer. Then you say you want to provide two lists and get an integer, so that doesn't line up. So I don't know what `result/3` really does. You haven't given an example of a valid `result/3` call. `and_list` returns just the subset of 0's from a list of 0's and 1's?  What you've written won't work. You don't have a clause for the case where an element is 0.